# Lot of delay in receiving timeline cards

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

In my case, the Glassware is inserting a jpeg image as a timeline card as a response to User's Voice query using "Take a note" Voice command. I keep waiting sometimes 10-15 mins before I see that timeline card on Glass. Sometimes, I see the inserted timeline card on Glass device only after I reboot the Glass device.

The way I have implemented this is:-
I do the Boot-strapping, that also includes inserting my Glassware Contact that accepts Voice command "Take a Note". Then on Glass I make a voice query using "Take a note", my Glassware accepts that query, sends an OK message to the Mirror Service and then inserts a new Timeline with jpeg image.

The Glass displays the Voice query however, it is not able to receive the inserted Timeline card in a consistent way.

Comment: There are actually at least two delays at work here: the delay for your server to receive voice command notification and the delay for your Glass to get the inserted timeline card. I suspect your case is the latter, but can you log these two times and elaborate where the delay comes from? This will make it easier to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Also, one way I trigger a timeline-Glass sync for testing is that I perform an action with a Gmail message on my timeline (e.g. star). Can you try doing that when you are waiting for your timeline card to be inserted and see if your card quickly appears after that action?

Comment: do you see the card in the playground ? If you see it here then check your network settings for glass https://developers.google.com/glass/playground

Comment: I am using my Glassware( an extension of java-quick-start project) to serve up the image timeline card. I did the testing, and on the Voice query, the image card is served up in 2-3 seconds on my Glassware web-page, but even w/ the Gmail action, it may take upto 2 minutes to show up on my glass. What I did find is that, after I restart my Glassware Jetty server, I send a timeline card from my Glassware and after I receive it on Glass, I do a Voice quiery and the response is pretty fast.

Comment: could you please point me to the location, where it says, how to deploy Java-starter-project to Google App Engine. I want to use the Google infrastructure to deploy my Glassware and check if that improves the performance of timeline cards rendering to Glass.

Comment: I was able to install the Glassware on Google App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

We're currently investigating the issue, which seems to be affecting multiple users. Please keep an eye on [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=185) on our issue tracker for more information.

**8/23/2013:** We believe that the cause of this issue has been tracked down and fixed. If you still find yourself experiencing significant lag times, please let us know via the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=185).

Comment: After installing the Glassware on Google App Engine, the response time has improved.

Comment: Still experiencing this issue as of today. I tested with an app that pushes a simple text item to the timeline. There seem to be periods of time in which all pushes are immediately visible on the Glass, and at other times it takes anywhere from a few minutes to an hour to show up on the Glass (at which point all pushes that didn't show up suddenly appear at once, similar to rubber-banding in games).

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue as uberwulu. I've starred the issue on Google's Issue Tracker, emailed support today. Nothing.